# Custom messages for Github Slack integration for issue tracking

Tags: github, slack, slack-api, git-webhooks

Is it possible to customize the messages that github will send to the slack webhook? I was able to set it up to where I get notifications whenever an issue is created/deleted/edited, however I would like to only get notifications for specific issues with a certain label and also be able to change the format of the notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this level of customization, you will likely need to write a bit of custom code that:

1. Receives and authenticates the [Github webhook](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/about-webhooks). This means you need to host the code someplace as a web service, for example in [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/).
2. Filters down to only the events that matter to you with the custom criteria you listed above.
3. Formats a custom Slack message in [markdown](https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting) based on the payload of the Github event.
4. Posts that message to Slack - probably the simplest solution is to use the [Slack incoming webhooks](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks).

(Disclosure: I am the co-founder of Fusebit). [Fusebit](https://fusebit.io) automates such integration scenarios and allows you to focus on the parts that matter to you, which in this case is the custom filtering and custom message formatting code.